# Merge multiple Excel files starting at row in R

Tags: r, excel, merge

I have multiple Excel files that I need to merge into one, but only certain rows. The Excel files look like this...

The column headers are identical for all files. I also need to add a new column A to the newly generated file, so I created a separate Excel file with just the headers and the new column A. My script first reads in this file (below) and writes it to the workbook...

Next, I need to read each file, starting at row 9 and merge all the data, one after another. So the final result should look like this (minus the Member site column, I haven't attempted the logic for that yet, but thinking it will be a substring of the Specimen ID value)...

However, my current result is...

I am currently only using 3 files, each with a few dozen rows, to start, but the end goal is to merge about 15-30 files, each with 25 to 200 rows, give or take. So...

1) I know my code is incorrect, but not sure how to get the intended results. For one, my loop is overwriting data because it's constantly starting at row/column 2 when it writes. However, I can't think how to rewrite this.

2) The dates are returning in General format ("43008" instead of "9/30/2017")

3) Certain columns data is being placed under different columns (like Nucleic Acid Concentration has the values from the Date of Tissue Content).

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

My code...

```
library(openxlsx)   # Excel and csv files
library(svDialogs)   # Dialog boxes

setwd("C:/Users/Work/Combined Manifest")

# Create and load Excel file
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add worksheet
addWorksheet(wb, "Template")

# Read in & write header file
df.headers <- read.xlsx("headers.xlsx", sheet = "Template")

writeData(wb, "Template", df.headers, colNames = TRUE)

# Function to get user path
getPath <- function() { 
  # Ask for path
  path <- dlgInput("Enter path to files: ", Sys.info()["user"])$res
  if (dir.exists(path)) {
    # If path exists, set the path as the working directory
    return(path)
  } else {
    # If not, issue an error and recall the getPath function
    dlg_message("Error: The path you entered is not a valid directory. Please try again.")$res
    getPath()
  }
}

# Call getPath function
folder <- getPath()

setwd(folder)

# Get list of files in directory
pattern.ext <- "\\.xlsx$"
files <- dir(folder, full=TRUE, pattern=pattern.ext)

# Get basenames and remove extension 
files.nms <- basename(files)
files.nms <- gsub(pattern.ext, "", files.nms)

# Set the names
names(files) <- files.nms

# Iterate to read in files and write to new file
for (nm in files.nms) {

  # Read in files 
  df <- read.xlsx((files[nm]), sheet = "Template", startRow = 9, colNames = FALSE)

  # Write data to sheet
  writeData(wb, "Template", df, startCol = 2, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "Combined.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

**EDIT:**
So with the loop below, I am successfully reading in the files and merging them. Thanks for all the help!

```
for (nm in files.nms) {

  # Read in files 
  df <- read.xlsx(files[nm], sheet = "Template", startRow = 8, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE,
                  skipEmptyCols = FALSE)

  # Append the data
  allData <- rbind(allData, df)
}
```

**EDIT: FINAL SOLUTION**
Thanks to everyone for the help!!

```
library(openxlsx)   # Excel and csv files
library(svDialogs)   # Dialog boxes

# Create and load Excel file
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add worksheet
addWorksheet(wb, "Template")

# Function to get user path
getPath <- function() { 
  # Ask for path
  path <- dlgInput("Enter path to files: ", Sys.info()["user"])$res
  if (dir.exists(path)) {
    # If path exists, set the path as the working directory
    return(path)
  } else {
    # If not, issue an error and recall the getPath function
    dlg_message("Error: The path you entered is not a valid directory. Please try again.")$res
    getPath()
  }
}

# Call getPath function
folder <- getPath()

# Set working directory
setwd(folder)

# Get list of files in directory
pattern.ext <- "\\.xlsx$"
files <- dir(folder, full=TRUE, pattern=pattern.ext)

# Get basenames and remove extension 
files.nms <- basename(files)

# Set the names
names(files) <- files.nms

# Create empty dataframe
allData <- data.frame()

# Create list (reserve memory)
f.List <- vector("list",length(files.nms))

# Look and load files
for (nm in 1:length(files.nms)) {

  # Read in files
  f.List[[nm]] <- read.xlsx(files[nm], sheet = "Template", startRow = 8, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE,
                  skipEmptyCols = FALSE)
}

# Append the data
allData <- do.call("rbind", f.List)

# Add a new column as 'Member Site'
allData <- data.frame('Member Site' = "", allData)

# Take the substring of the Specimen.ID column for Memeber Site
allData$Member.Site <- sapply(strsplit(allData$Specimen.ID, "-"), "[", 2)

# Write data to sheet
writeData(wb, "Template", startCol = 1, allData)

# Save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "Combined.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are providing a lot of information in your question, which is generally a good thing, but I’m wondering if you could make your problems easier to solve by recreating the problem using fewer and smaller files. Could you figure out how to merge two files, each containing a small amount of data first?

With regards to the first challenge you raise:

1) Yes you are overwriting the workbook in each loop. I would suggest you load the data and append it to a data.frame and then store the end result after loading all the files. Have a look at the example below. Please note that this example uses rbind, which is inefficient if you are combining a large number of files. So if you have many files you may need to use a different structure.

```
# Create and empty data frame
allData <- data.frame()

# Loop and load files
for(nm in files.nms) {

    # Read in files 
    df <- read.xlsx((files[nm]), sheet = "Template", startRow = 9, colNames = FALSE)

    # Append the data
    allData <- rbind(allData, df)

}

# Write data to sheet
writeData(wb, "Template", df, startCol = 2, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE)
```

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you need!

**Edit: Updating the answer to address the comments made**

If you have more then a few files, rbind will get slow like @Parfait mentioned due to multiple copies of the data being made. The way to avoid this, is by first reserving space in memory by creating an empty list with enough space to hold your data, then fill in the list, and only at the end merge all the data together using do.call("rbind", ...) . I've compiled some sample code below that's in line with what you provided in your question.

```
# Create list (reserve memory)
f.List <- vector("list",length(files.nms))

# Loop and load files
for(eNr in 1:length(files.nms)) {

    # Read in files 
    f.List[[eNr]] <- read.xlsx((files.nms[eNr]), sheet = "Template", startRow = 9)

}

# Append the data
allData <- do.call("rbind", f.List)
```

Below to illustrate this further, a small reproducible example. It uses just a couple of data frames, but it illustrates the process of creating a list, populating that list, and merging the data as the last step.

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:1)
df2 <- data.frame(y=4:6, x=3:1)
df.List <- list(df1,df2)

# Create list
d.List <- vector("list",length(df.List))

# Loop and add data
for(eNr in 1:length(df.List)) {
    d.List[[eNr]] <- df.List[[eNr]] 
}

# Bind all at once
dfAll <- do.call("rbind", d.List)
print(dfAll)
```

Hope this help! Thanks!

Comment: It is not advised to use `rbind` inside a loop. It leads to excessive copying. See Patrick Burn's [R Interno - Circle 2: Growing Objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Instead, build a list of data frames and `rbind` once outside the loop.

Comment: @MatAff, thanks for you response. I should have clarified, I am currently only attempting to use 3 of the files, each with a few dozen rows. I will be combining around 15-30 files, each with anywhere from 25 to 200 rows. What function other than rbind would you suggest?

Comment: @MatAff, using your code it returns the following error: `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match`. I've doubled check the files, all columns are good.

Comment: Possibly it is due to `colNames = FALSE` in @MatAff's code. Since all Excel files are structurally the same, read in **with** headers and then just add your *Member Site* column.

Comment: @Parfait, wouldn't that read in the headers into the dataframe multiple times?

Comment: Headers will be applied to a temporary `df` (single object) within the loop that is then rbinded with other dfs. Also, `rbind` does not extend headers if that was your question. It matches `colnames` and then retains one set.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I provided my implementation in my question. So far, I have the empty column A and the data sets merged. Just need to try to get the substring for the Member Site column. Thanks again!