# Read and merge multiple xlsx files with different structure in R

Tags: r

I would like to read and merge multiple (>20) .xlsx files using R.

This is how my .xlsx files look.

```
Sample  X  Y  Z
Sample1  5  3  1
Sample2  4  1  11
Sample3  9  11  9


Sample  A  B  Z
Sample4  12  1  1
Sample5  6  1.1  1.41
Sample6  7  91  1


Sample  C  A  Z
Sample7  4  2  9
Sample8  98  11  61
```

I would like to merge them into a single df with the Headers "Sample", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C". In no particular order, but it should contain all.

I found a few solutions which work with .xlsx files with the same structure (e.g. [Merge multiple Excel files starting at row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977786/merge-multiple-excel-files-starting-at-row-in-r)) but they won't work with my problem.

Comment: @RonakShah no need to merge here i think? Looks like we can do with rowbinding, for example using `data.table::rbindlist( mylist, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: @Wimpel you are right, there is no column to merge here. So row binding is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RonakShah and @Wimpel, this works:

```
#path to files
path <- "C:/Users/your/path"

#list diles
filenames_list <- list.files(path= path, full.names=TRUE)

#Store files in a list
All <- lapply(filenames_list,function(filename){
    read.xlsx(filename)
 })

#merge the dfs
merged_df <- data.table::rbindlist(All, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily achieved via `dplyr::bind_rows` which in contrast to `rbind` allows for binding df's by row with differing number of columns and column names:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "Sample  X  Y  Z
Sample1  5  3  1
Sample2  4  1  11
Sample3  9  11  9", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "Sample  A  B  Z
Sample4  12  1  1
Sample5  6  1.1  1.41
Sample6  7  91  1", header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = "Sample  C  A  Z
Sample7  4  2  9
Sample8  98  11  61", header = TRUE)

df <- list(df1, df2, df3)

dplyr::bind_rows(df)
#>    Sample  X  Y     Z  A    B  C
#> 1 Sample1  5  3  1.00 NA   NA NA
#> 2 Sample2  4  1 11.00 NA   NA NA
#> 3 Sample3  9 11  9.00 NA   NA NA
#> 4 Sample4 NA NA  1.00 12  1.0 NA
#> 5 Sample5 NA NA  1.41  6  1.1 NA
#> 6 Sample6 NA NA  1.00  7 91.0 NA
#> 7 Sample7 NA NA  9.00  2   NA  4
#> 8 Sample8 NA NA 61.00 11   NA 98
```